# how to limit user into inputting only INT

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating an onlineshop and I want to use Javascript ( I think) or JQuery, in order when the user is entering details for adding a new product into the database, like:
-Title (TEXT)
-Price (FLOAT)
-Description (TEXT)
-Quantity Available (INT)

How to set a check to occur and inform the user that he has an incorrect data type for a specific field? Because now my database lets the user add whatever he wants, and at the preview of the product the field price shows "£0". Also, if the check completes for all the fields and is okay, a message will be shown that it okay.

code below

```
<div id="addForm">
     <div id="formHeading"><h2>Add Product</h2></div><p>
    <p>
    <form id = "additems" action="../cms/insert.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"/>
    <div id="formContents">
      <label for="title">Title of your product:
      <div id="formContents"> </label><input type="text" name="title" style="width: 180px" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value=''"    
            onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue" 
            value=" title of your product here" maxlength="19" /><p>
      </div>
          <div id="formContents">
      <label for="description">Description of your product:
      <div id="formContents"> </label><input type="text" name="description" style="width: 180px" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value=''"    
            onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue" 
            value="description of the product" maxlength="19" /><p>
      </div>
      <label for="price">Price:      &pound;    </label><input type="INT" name="price" style="width: 40px" /><p>
      <label for="stock">Quantity:</label><input type="text" name="stock" style="width: 40px" />
      <p>    
      </div>
```

Comment: Client side validation is good, but you still also must use server side validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it two ways:

1. prevent him from entering anything other than intended characters :
   for example , for fields that would have INT values :

> $('.nonly').bind('keyup blur',function(){$(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^0-9]/g,''));});

1. validate after entering :

> ```
> var intRegex = /^\d+$/;
> var cellphone = $('#register_phonenum');  
> if ((cellphone.val()=='')||(!intRegex.test(cellphone.val()))) {
>     /* do something*/
>     return false;
> }
> ```

Comment: you should do it both ways, validation is never enough